# What does "siehste mal" mean?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I'm trying to find a translation, but it seems to be so informal that it doesn't appear properly in dictionaries.

The context would be like:

```
A: Do you know Hans?
B: The new guy?
A sends a picture
B: Achso
A: Siehste mal?
```

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the final reaction of `A`, but [`siehste`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/siehste) is an informal contraction of `siehst du`. Also see the example 8a [on the Duden website](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sehen).

Comment: This conversation makes no sense.

Comment: Funny that A talks first english, then german to B. Not very convincing this is original.

Answer (score 3):

*Siehste mal*, which is the colloquial short reduction of *Siehst du einmal*, can have different meanings depending on the situation context. Here we have

```
A: Do you know Hans?     / Kennst du Hans?
B: The new guy?          / Den neuen Typen?
A sends a picture        / A schickt ein Bild
B: Achso                 / Oh, I see
```

The reaction of A as one wants to translate is not very logical because B has already had a look at it, and this question actually comes too late:

```
A: Siehste mal?          / Schaust du einmal darauf? / Can you have a look now?
```

Better appropriate would be an exclamation mark (if that was just a typo?) and the meaning would turn into:

```
A: Siehste mal!          / Da kannst du aber mal sehen! / Look look!
```

or, without question tag, it could mean a very colloquial short form of:

```
A: Siehste mal           / Da hast du ihn jetzt mal gesehen. / Now you've seen him.
```

The word *mal* (which means *einmal*) is the time aspect and emphases this moment.

Answer (score -2):

A more credible conversation would be:

> A: Sei vorsichtig! Die Herdplatte ist noch heiß.
>
> B: (berührt mit trotzigem Gesichtsausdruck die Herdplatte, es zischt kurz) Auu! (weint)
>
> A: Siehste, ich hab's dir doch gesagt! Aber auf Muttern muß man ja nicht hören, gä?

So, `siehste` is `siehst du` and `siehste mal` is `siehst du einmal` which is roughly equivalent to `So, there you have it!`

Comment: It's good that you provided a better example, but you didn't really answer the question since you didn't explain what `siehste` means.

Comment: (+1) I think it could/should be saved by adding a line. I didin't know what *siehste* mean, and the example is self-explanatory.

Comment: »gä«? :-))  Ist das jetzt Westphälisch oder was? ;-)

Comment: @Alfe Dort hieße es eher "woll?", wa?

Comment: Und wo ist »gä« gebräuchlich?

Comment: @Alfe Mit Sicherheit kann ich es nur für Ostthüringen sagen, denke aber, daß es von Sachsen, über Franken und Hessen bis runter zum Bodensee zu hören ist, wobei der Vokal alle Werte zwischen e und a inklusive annehmen kann.

Comment: Ach, als _gell_ im Bodenseebereich erkenn ich es jetzt wieder.

Comment: Ich höre weder auf Muttern noch auf Schrauben.